# Get previous .apk package

Tags: android, android-keystore

At first, I made app using [this](https://appery.io/), then I uploaded it to the play store.

Now I redesigned my app using Android Studio and it is now asking me for keystore file. How to get that from previous .apk package.

Answer (score 1):

Taking reference from [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

You can find it from the following path

> **app/build/apk/app-release.apk**

When you sign your app, google suggest you to do the following:

> Note: Including the passwords for your release key and keystore inside the build file is not a good security practice. Alternatively, you can configure the build file to obtain these passwords from environment variables or have the build process prompt you for these passwords.

Warning by google, **You cannot publish any updates, if you lost/ not saved the previous key.**

> **Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.**